# Compiler errors when using BibTeX

Tags: latex, bibtex, bibliography, biblatex

I have tried to compile some work in LaTeX, using the command `pdflatex seminararbeit` first, which compiled well.

After that, I tried `bibtex seminararbeit`, which resulted in this:

```
I found no \citation commands---while reading file seminararbeit.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file seminararbeit.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file seminararbeit.aux
```

My `seminararbeit.tex` file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[final,bibliography=totocnumbered]{include/sikseminar}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true,linkcolor = black,citecolor = black,urlcolor = black,filecolor = black}
\graphicspath{{./figures/}}
\clubpenalty=10000  
\widowpenalty=10000

\overfullrule=1mm

\begin{document}

\newpage
\citation{ kopka00latex1}

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

While `seminararbeit.bib` looks like this:

```
@book{ kopka00latex1,
  author = "Helmut Kopka",
  title = "{LATEX, Band 1 -- Einf{\"u}hrung}",
  publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
  address = "München",
  year = {2000},
  edition = {3., überarbeitete Auflage},
  isbn = {3-8273-1557-3}
}
```

The problem is, that I need to use the packages I included, I guess that's the root of the problem.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `\citation`. Instead use `\cite`.